# How get uncached value from localStorage

Tags: javascript, vue.js, browser-cache

I store Access token for authorization in javascript `localStorage`. Every time when my frontend app loaded I want get this token for get user.

```
  created() {
    let access = localStorage.getItem('access')
    console.log(access)
    if (!access) {
      console.log('access not exists')
    } else {
      console.log('access exists:', access)
    }
  }
```

But this token should has overwrited quite often. And when I clean this token because user logout I should get null value in Access. But chrome cache this value and 'if' block still get token like existed.
This what i see in console:
[image]

How I can get uncached value? Or I should leave this. And it will disturb in production?

Comment: It looks like you are storing a undefined value in storage and the reason the if doesnt work is because that undefined value gets converted to a string and thus is truthy. Can you show how you are storing and removing the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local Storage is not cached.
I assume the issue is the way how you clean local storage. I assume you are doing something like this: `localStorage.setItem('access', undefined)`. This will set the local storage item to the string `'undefined'`, and if you do `if (!access)` it will always return false. You currently cannot use `undefined`, `null` or `true` / `false` in local storage, [only strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API). You can check the stored type by printing the returned type: `console.log(typeof localStorage.getItem('access'))`, which should be string.

You have 2 options:

**Remove the item completely from local storage**

`localStorage.removeItem('access')`

Then you can use your current implementation, as local storage will return `undefined` on `localStorage.getItem('access')`.

**Set an empty string and test for string length:**

```
// "clean" your access
localStorage.setItem('access', '');

// Check if there is an access
const access = localStorage.getItem('access');
if (access && access.length > 0) {
  console.log('access does exists')
} else {
  console.log('access does NOT exists')    
}
```

Comment: When would it be beneficial to set an empty string to remove the value instead of just use the removeItem method ?

Comment: @Tommi In case you want to check if the value has already been initialized before, for example to see if it is a returning user. But of course you could just set another value like `isreturninguser` for that. I guess the first method would be best for OP case.